# running a python script in termin os x

Tags: python

I do not know why but I cannot run a python script though the terminal.

my script:

define_regions.py

```
print "Hello World!"
print "Hello Again"
print "I like typing this."
print "This is fun."
print 'Yay! Printing.'
print "I'd much rather you 'not'."
print 'I "said" do not touch this.'
```

terminal:

```
pik:scripts katja$ python define_regions.py
pik:scripts katja$
```

It does not execute it somehow and I do not understand why.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
run python

```
pik:scripts katja$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 

python -V
Python 2.7.6

pik:scripts katja$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

EDIT2

```
pik:scripts katja$ python ./define_regions.py
pik:scripts katja$ python -c 'import sys; print sys.path'
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-12.0.5-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
pik:scripts katja$ python -c 'print "test"'
test
```

Comment: What does `python -V` say? Does the REPL work, what does it do if you just run `python` on the commandline? What is the output of `which python`?

Comment: @onurgüngör I have edited my question with the information of yours

Comment: Now try `python ./define_regions.py`. Second, run `python -c 'import sys; print sys.path'`, third try running `python -c 'print "test"'`

Comment: @onurgüngör edited it again, ./define_regions did not work

Comment: Interesting. Are you sure you got something in ./define_regions.py? Can you run `cat ./define_regions.py`?

Comment: you are a genius, haha I do not know how but I had two copies of the script and one I edited all the time but it was not used by the terminal. Thank you